# Making Submit and Reset have a different border from the input tag border

Tags: html, css

Please how can i make the submit button and reset button have a different border apart from the input tags

```
     HTML
     <input typ="image" name="submit"     value=" " scr="image.png">

      <input type="image" name="reset"      value=" " scr="reset.png" >

   CSS
   input, textarea, select {
   border: 2px solid red;
   }
```

I have tried to add another selector with the name submit and reset but both of them still get the values from the input tags border.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`input[type=image]` or give them a `class` name or give them an `id`, `name` is not used for css

Comment: Is it a chrome thing that I am able to use [the name attribute](http://jsfiddle.net/PeeHaa/sZVUJ/1/)?

Comment: ah interesting, i guess you could use name

Answer (score 0):

Write:

```
id="submit"
```

In the input tag of the submit button, and then in the CSS, type:

```
#submit
{
    border: 1px solid black;     /* as an example */
}
```